# (Lack of) Availability of Finite-Difference library for simple 2D PDEs

Tags: finite-difference, python, r, octave, scilab

I would like to solve two types of simple 2D problems, namely the stationary heat equation on an L shaped geometry like this:

[image]

And also compute the magnetostactic field in an air gap of the following geometry:

[image]

Since it wouldn’t be smart to reinvent the wheel, I searched for an open-source library that could handle such problems. At far as I could tell, neither in Python, Octave, Scilab or R there is a Finite-Difference (FD) library that could handle this type of geometries, which is not rectangular but should nonetheless fit on a rectangular grid (if I remember correctly from reading from “Heat Transfer” from Incropera, internal and external nodes can be handled by FD)

This lack of availability strikes me as odd;  Python, Octave, Scilab and R all of them have built-in libraries for solution of ODEs, but why not FD for PDEs? Was it concluded that focusing on Finite-Element (FE) would be enough/better? I would like to stay with FD for two reasons: simplicity and I would like in the future to solve other types of PDEs, which may not be available on a FE solver.

Would it make sense to think of developing such a library? Are the limitations of FD (to simple geometries) not worth the effort?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In a sense an ODE package is a tool for solving PDEs, you just need to provide a grid and spatial discretization of your PDEs, and use the method of lines

Comment: I would like to solve boundarz value problems, so no time dependency, as far as I know, MOL is only for time-dependent PDEs

Comment: In principle you can solve boundary problems with MOL by relaxation, using artificial time.

Comment: I found a library called findiff in like 2 seconds, how much redearch have you done?

Comment: Ok perhaps one would have to implement the grid oneself, but the stencils are readily available at least.

Comment: I did enough research to realize that findiff only solves PDEs in a rectangular domain in 2D (and a cube in 3D)

Comment: I think your application is specialized enough that it doesn't warrant (or noone has bothered to publish in open source) routines written specifically for not-quite-rectangular domains. If you use math libraries to the extent possible, I'd say that's not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

It seems hard to write a general enough FD library thas has wide applicability, since FD methods are not as easy to write for general domains, unlike FEM which uses unstructured grids, for which there is a standard approach.

I know of two libraries which might be useful for you

Overture:
An Object-Oriented Toolkit for Solving Partial Differential Equations in Complex Geometry
http://www.overtureframework.org

OpenSBLI:
A framework for the automated derivation of finite difference solvers from high-level problem descriptions.
https://opensbli.github.io

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little bit late, but there's a third party library in Python which solve PDEs using FD, it is called [findiff](https://github.com/maroba/findiff). Check it out.